# RequestBuilder

Tags: gwt, javascript, java

Разрабатываю приложение используя GWT 2.1.0. Приложение является графическим интерфейсом пользователя сервиса ОС. Оно общается через HTTP-запросы. В ответе на запрос к сервису, через RequestBuilder, getStatusCode() объекта response всегда равен 0. Из-за чего это может быть? Серверная часть отвечает нормально, видно через wireshark.

Answer (score 1):

Хм.. так трудно что-то понять.. может вы спрашиваете статус-код раньше, чем ответ фактически пришёл?

Answer (score 1):

В [javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/http/client/RequestBuilder.html) по RequestBuildes написано, что модуль должен наследовать такой класс:

```
<module>
  <!-- other inherited modules, such as com.google.gwt.user.User -->
  <inherits name="com.google.gwt.http.HTTP"/>
  <!-- additional module settings -->
</module>
```

Вот еще полезный урок по [RequestBuilder](http://www.gwtapps.com/doc/html/com.google.gwt.http.client.html), где подробно все расписано.